# Read Xhtml file in android?

Tags: android, xhtml, epub, epublib

I see [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fidibo.reader&hl=en) application on google play . I have some question :

- What format are stored books and how read?

Is the format of books xhtml?

If it is true . How can I read xhtml ?

Should I use a specific library ?

I need guidance for production applications such as this have ?

In this app when change the size of font the count of characters change too.Is the page of epubs dynamic ?

Comment: there is a format of books called .epub  which is basically collection of html files . You can read .epub books by using epublib library

Comment: Please get me a link of best library for read of .epub with tutorial .

Comment: i personally used http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android  epublib , but there are already open sorce book reader app like pageturner https://github.com/NightWhistler/PageTurner  ,coolreader,daisy reader etc

Comment: @  Redman . Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can I set size for fonts with this  library (siegmann) ?

Comment: @ Redman .In this app when change the size of font the count of characters change too.Is the page of epubs dynamic ?

Comment: I dont know much about that app